# Why does Terraform plan recreate blocks when the configuration has not changed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a simple site set up on AWS and have a terraform script working to deploy it (at least from my local machine).

When I have a successful deployment through `terraform apply`, quite often if I then run `terraform plan` again (immediately after the `apply`) I will see changes like this:

```
  # aws_route53_record.alias_route53_record_portal will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_route53_record" "alias_route53_record_portal" {
        fqdn    = "mysite.co.uk"
        id      = "Z12345678UR1K1IFUBA_mysite.co.uk_A"
        name    = "mysite.co.uk"
        records = []
        ttl     = 0
        type    = "A"
        zone_id = "Z12345678UR1K1IFUBA"

      - alias {
          - evaluate_target_health = false -> null
          - name                   = "d12345mkpmx9ii.cloudfront.net" -> null
          - zone_id                = "Z2FDTNDATAQYW2" -> null
        }
          + evaluate_target_health = true
          + name                   = "d12345mkpmx9ii.cloudfront.net"
          + zone_id                = "Z2FDTNDATAQYW2"
        }
    }
```

Why is terraform saying that some parts of resources need recreating when nothing has changed?

**EDIT** My actual tf resource...

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "alias_route53_record_portal" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.sds_zone.zone_id
  name    = "mysite.co.uk"
  type    = "A"

  alias {
    name                    = aws_cloudfront_distribution.s3_distribution.domain_name
    zone_id                 = aws_cloudfront_distribution.s3_distribution.hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health  = true
  }
}
```

Comment: I noticed `evaluate_target_health` has changed from `false` to `true`. Maybe that's the reason why the the resource will be updated in place.

Comment: Do you actually have an `alias` block in the tf?

Comment: @jellycsc I just figured it would only update the fields which have changed, no?

Comment: @luk2302 Yes - I have just added the resource, from my actual .tf file, to the post.

Comment: @MattW Yes, I will just update the fields that have changed. The reason why it's showing like this is because often times AWS doesn't provide separate APIs for each field. Since TF is showing that this resource will be updated in-place, it will touch the minimum number of resources to make this change.

Comment: @jellycsc Please provide an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @MattW Thx, I've submitted the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have changed `evaluate_target_health` from `false` to `true`. Terraform will just update the fields that have changed. The reason why it's showing like this is because often times AWS doesn't provide separate APIs for each field. Since TF is showing that this resource will be updated in-place, it will touch the minimum number of resources to make this change.

Answer (score 1):

The "plan" operation in Terraform first synchronizes the Terraform state with remote objects (by making calls to the remote API), and then it compares the updated state with the configuration.

Terraform (or, more accurately, the relevant Terraform provider) then generates a planned update or replace for any case where the state and the configuration disagree.

If you see a planned update for a resource whose configuration you know you haven't changed, then by process of elimination that suggests that the *remote system* is what has changed.

Sometimes that can happen if some other process (or a human in the admin console) changes an object that Terraform believes itself to be responsible for. In that case, the typical resolution is to ensure that each object is only managed by one system and that no-one is routinely making changes to Terraform-managed objects outside of Terraform.

One way to diagnose this would be to consult the remote system and see whether its current settings agree with your Terraform configuration. If not, that would suggest that something other than Terraform has changed the value.

---

A less common reason this can arise is due to a bug in the provider itself. There are two variations of this class of bug:

- When creating the object, the provider doesn't correctly translate the given configuration to a remote API call, and so it ends up creating an object that doesn't match the configuration. A subsequent Terraform plan will then notice that inconsistency and plan an update to fix it. If the provider's *update* operation has a similar bug then this will never converge, causing the provider to repeatedly plan the same update.
- Conversely, the create/update may be implemented correctly but the "refresh" operation (updating the state to match the remote system) may inaccurately translate the remote object data back to Terraform state data, causing the state to not accurately reflect the remote system. In that case, the provider will probably then find that the configuration doesn't match the state anymore, even though the state *was* correct after the initial create.

Both of these bugs are typically nicknamed "permadiff" by provider developers, because the symptom is Terraform seeming to plan the same change indefinitely, no matter how many times you apply it. If you think you've encountered a "permadiff" bug then usually the path forward is to report a bug in the provider's development repository so that the maintainers can investigate.

One specific variation of "permadiff" is a situation where the remote system does some sort of normalization of your given values which the provider doesn't take into account. For example, some remote systems will accept strings containing uppercase letters but will convert them to lowercase for permanent storage. If a provider doesn't take that into account, it will probably incorrectly plan to change the value back to the one containing uppercase letters again in order to try to make the state match the configuration. This subclass of bug is a *normalization permadiff*, which provider teams will typically address by re-implementing the remote system's normalization logic in the provider itself.

If you find a *normalization permadiff* then you can often work around it until the bug is fixed by figuring out what normalization the remote system expects and then manually normalizing your configuration to match it, so that the provider will then see the configuration as matching the remote system.